# accessoryButtonTappedForRow called on Simulator but not Device

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a custom tableView set up that isn't dequeing cells. I'm not using statics cells in storyboard because I am using a UIViewController that contains the tableView. Regardless the set up is as follows :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
    // Array > Dictionary > cell.textLabel.text info here

    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
            switch (indexPath.row) {
                case 4:
                    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
                    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailButton;
                //etc etc
```

The cells are identically set up as the above code shows.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSIndexPath *pubdisclaimer = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:2];
    NSIndexPath *maintenanceInfo = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:4 inSection:0];

    if (indexPath == pubdisclaimer) {
        NSLog(@"Disclaimer Tapped");
        //Show UIAlertController
    } else if (indexPath == maintenanceInfo) {
    NSLog(@"Maintenance tapped");
        //Show Different UIAlertController
    } else {
        //
    }
}
```

The accessoryButtonTapped is detected in the simulator (and the different UIAlertControllers populate accordingly) however, when running on the device of the same deployment target as the simulator nothing happens but the button highlighting. This works fine with one indexPath but when I included the else if statement it doesn't call on the device.

FYI All tableView delegate and datasource is set properly to the file owner. Like I said everything is working fine until I add the second NSIndexPath so that leads me to believe thats where the issue lays. But if that is the case, why does it work perfectly in the simulator, even differentiating the two different button indexes? I think i'm missing something simple here. How to trouble shoot?

***EDIT*** logging indexPaths:

**SIMULATOR RETURNS**

```
2015-01-05 21:42:54.666 [38440:9202972] didSelectRowAtIndexPath section: 0, row: 4
2015-01-05 21:42:57.993 [38440:9202972] accessoryButtonTapped section: 0, row: 4
2015-01-05 21:43:04.765 [38440:9202972] didSelectRowAtIndexPath section: 2, row: 2
2015-01-05 21:43:08.185 [38440:9202972] accessoryButtonTapped section: 2, row: 2
```

**DEVICE RETURNS**

```
2015-01-05 21:45:17.564 [4072:1128326] didSelectRowAtIndexPath section: 0, row: 4
2015-01-05 21:45:19.763 [4072:1128326] Nothing tapped : else
2015-01-05 21:45:28.613 [4072:1128326] didSelectRowAtIndexPath section: 2, row: 2
2015-01-05 21:45:29.313 [4072:1128326] Nothing tapped : else
```

Comment: Add an alert in `else` block as well, and check if your condition is going to there or not.

Comment: @Mrunal tested, results as you suspected. Both accessory buttons NSLog to the else statement. Which confirms both indexPaths are correct. However, still confused why it works on the simulator. What do you suggest

Comment: NSLog(@"section: %d, row: %d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row); on both simulator and device. Then compare why its coming different for both. Here you require to deep dive into code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `if` condition and break it into `row` and `section` separately.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

// PubDisclaimer
    if ((indexPath.row == 2 && indexPath.section == 2)) {
        NSLog(@"Disclaimer Tapped");
        //Show UIAlertController
    } 
// MaintenanceInfo
    else if ((indexPath.row == 4 && indexPath.section == 0)) {
        NSLog(@"Maintenance tapped");
        //Show Different UIAlertController
    } 
    else {
        NSLog(@"Nothing tapped");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sadly, this works. And I say sadly not because I am sad, because I don't understand ha. Thanks for __fixing__ me, but can you offer knowledge on why it has to be set this way, especially since the indexes were explicitly set, and any theories on why it worked on simulator but not device? I'm here to learn, not just get code :) Thanks

Comment: `==` might be not working with `NSIndexPath` references, I don't know but give a try with `EqualsTo` method of `NSObject` class with both indexPath references.

Comment: I normally do comparing in this manner. Glad to know that the same helps you. Can you please upvote the answer. Sorry for the typo, I had directly wrote in answer box, have not checked with XCode.

Answer (score 1):

`==` for objects tests for pointer equality, not "does this index path have the same row and section as that one".

If it's working on the simulator, it's luck and should not be depended on, possibly some low-numbered index paths are being cached like some low-numbered NSNumbers are for efficiency. You should compare objects with `isEqual:`:

```
 if ([indexPath isEqual:maintenanceInfo])
```